# Reading a java program

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, file

I am trying to read a java program.

I am using this line of code.

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

Does it also split the ';' from the previous variable name?

for Example

```
int x = test;
```

How would the split, SPLIT that?

Comment: Try it and see if it does or not.

Comment: `int x = test` I'm sorry but what is this?  What do you mean how does splitting a String affect an _integer_

Comment: Note that 'tokenizing' a Java program is quite a complicated process and can't be done with just simple calls to split.

Comment: why should it split at `;` - computers do what you *order* them to do, not what you want them to do - nowhere you specified a `;` (BTW, as greg wrote, it is not trivial, lots of spaces are optional e.g. `int x=test;` (no spaces around equal) is valid)

Comment: if there were 2 spaces? would it split the space also as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the line was `int x = test;` and you specified `line.split(" ")`, it would split on the **" "** character (empty space), so

```
words=["int","x","=","test;"]
```

You specify the character that you want to split the line on inside of the split method. So if my line was `"Hi#I'm;#Bob"` and I ran `String[] words = line.split("#")`, the result would be

```
words = ["Hi","I'm;",Bob"].
```

It won't effect the **';'** character unless you specify

Answer (score 0):

No, line.split(" ") only separate each word by the space character. In your case,

```
int x = test;
```

Space characters are between "int" and "x", "x" and "=", "=" and "test;", so the output will be,

```
word[0]="int";
word[1]="x";
word[2]="=";
word[3]="test;";
```

If you want to split by both space and semicolon, then use regular expression,

```
String[] words = line.split("[ ;]");
```

Comment: why the backslash?

Comment: where did you got that? link for that tutorial please! 20+ years and I never heard that, always thought it is for escaping special characters  (like `\\.` to get a point, or `\\-` inside `[]`) - there is no need for OR inside `[]` - they actually mean any of the listed characters (or in the given range - {OR is `|`} but outside `[]`s)

Comment: and, BTW, I prefer the official documentation: [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - please, you check that

Comment: still wrong, as I already wrote "*no need for OR inside `[]`*", actually above code is now splitting at spaces, semi-colons and `|`

Comment: if there were 2 spaces? would it split the space also as a string?